# Show debug logs when deployed (Firebase Hosting)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I wanted to catch some errors that is happening on a dev application hosted on firebase hosting the app is build with react native for web and i have set the firebase option to debug like this `setLogLevel("debug")` and this shows me all the logs when testing locally but i also want to be able to see the logs when the app is deployed using firebase cli, is there an option to do that?